# Online Music Player that supports .MIDI files

Tags: javascript, midi, audio-player

Long story short:

Basically, what I'm looking to set up is an on-site music player that allows the user to add/remove their own songs to some sort of playlist while having some .MIDI files in it by default, without requiring them to install any new plugins or other software they wouldn't already *likely* have, so JavaScript, Flash or HTML5 etc. are some acceptable options, and it doesn't matter if it doesn't work in Internet Explorer :P

I am aware of the ability to play *individual* .MIDI files in a browser, that is not what I'm looking for.

I got *really close* to achieving this with [soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), which I can use jQuery to inject a custom playlist into, however... when I tried playing a .MIDI file from the playlist, my browser downloads the file instead. :(

Other on-site music players seem to share the same lack of support for .MIDI files by default.

If there's any way to make soundmanager2's bar-ui music player play .MIDI files i've got everything else covered already.

I haven't been able to find any other solutions, but am open to anything as long as it meets the above given criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best online midi player I've found so far. Has a nice retro, synthesizer sound to it, with I'm Pretty sure every instrument being set to a certain preset.

http://wonderfl.net/c/4IH3

Comment: Link-only answers are highly discouraged here because the links may become dead in the future. I suggest you edit your answer with quotes from the sources you cite

Comment: Seriously!? Someone finally replied!? And what a reply! That player works perfectly, just what I needed, thank you so much!!! It makes my .MIDI files sound rather differently than on my old computer though, rather unsuitable as some background instruments (like drums) play significantly louder than lead instruments (like electric guitars and violins) in SiON, do you know if there's any way to change/fix that? But again, thanks for sharing, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

just finished to build the web at guitar.mine.nu
You can upload midi files. The parsing is performed
int he background by musescore to convert to XML then
the XML score music sheet is loaded by alphatab